# SublimeREPL can't find 'pry' even when installed

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, pry, sublimerepl, package-control

I Installed SublimeREPL via PackageControl.

When I tried running SublimeREPL for a ruby file in Sublime Text, the following error came out:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'pry' (>= 0) among 12 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /Users/ricky/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Ruby/pry_repl.rb:2:in `<main>'

***Repl Closed***
```

Just in case, I checked whether pry was installed:

```
gem list | grep pry
pry (0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.9.12)
```

What is it that I am missing in order to get SublimeREPL working?

Comment: Do you restart the sublime?

Answer (score 2):

I met the same error, there are something wrong with your gem path, fix by adding following to User's settings for SublimeREPL:(Preferences -> Packages Settings -> SublimeREPL -> User)

```js
{ 
    // default_extend_env are used to augment any environment variables
    // that should be visible for all subprocess repls launched within
    // SublimeREPL. This is a very good place to add PATH extension
    // once "PATH": "{PATH}:/home/username/mylocalinstalls/bin" or whatever
        "default_extend_env": {
        "PATH": "{HOME}/.rvm/bin/:/usr/local/bin/:{PATH}"
          }
}
```

If doesn't work, you can get more info form [here](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/168)